# Valuation of a Vanilla Interest Rate Swap using the "RQuantLib" Package

Tags: r

I am modelling a Vanilla Interest Rate Swap using the "RQuantLib" Package. I am following the example given in the Cran Paper "RQuantLib". For the Fixed Leg of the Interest Rate Swap, the given R code in the example is;

```
bond <- list(faceAmount=100,
         issueDate=as.Date("2004-11-30"),
         maturityDate=as.Date("2008-11-30"),
         redemption=100, 
         effectiveDate=as.Date("2004-11-30"))
dateparams <- list(settlementDays=1,
                   calendar="us", dayCounter = 'Thirty360', period=2, 
                   businessDayConvention = 4, terminationDateConvention=4,
                   dateGeneration=1, endOfMonth=1)

coupon.rate <- c(0.02875)

params <- list(tradeDate=as.Date('2002-2-15'),
               settleDate=as.Date('2002-2-19'),
               dt=.25,
               interpWhat="discount",
               interpHow="loglinear")
setEvaluationDate(as.Date("2004-11-22"))

discountCurve.flat <- DiscountCurve(params, list(flat=0.05))
FixedRateBond(bond, coupon.rate, discountCurve.flat, dateparams)


#Same bond with a discount curve constructed from market quotes
tsQuotes <- list(d1w  =0.0382,
                 d1m  =0.0372,
                 fut1=96.2875,
                 fut2=96.7875,
                 fut3=96.9875,
                 fut4=96.6875,
                 fut5=96.4875,
                 fut6=96.3875,
                 fut7=96.2875,
                 fut8=96.0875,
                 s3y  =0.0398,
                 s5y  =0.0443,
                 s10y =0.05165,
                 s15y =0.055175)

discountCurve <- DiscountCurve(params, tsQuotes)
FixedRateBond(bond, coupon.rate, discountCurve, dateparams)


#example with default dateparams
FixedRateBond(bond, coupon.rate, discountCurve)

##exampe with defaul bond parameter and dateparams
bond <- list(issueDate=as.Date("2004-11-30"),
             maturityDate=as.Date("2008-11-30"))
dateparams <- list(calendar="us",
                   dayCounter = "ActualActual", 
                   period="Annual")
FixedRateBond(bond, coupon.rate, discountCurve, dateparams)
```

However, in this R Code the following transcripts are showing errors;

```
setEvaluationDate(as.Date("2004-11-22"))

discountCurve.flat <- DiscountCurve(params, list(flat=0.05))
```

and the errors are as below;

```
> setEvaluationDate(as.Date("2004-11-22"))
Error: could not find function "setEvaluationDate"
> discountCurve.flat <- DiscountCurve(params, list(flat=0.05))
Error: could not find function "DiscountCurve"
```

I have tried to investigate why the R Code is failing to compile but I failed. Can anyone assist please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you didn't *load the package* :

`R> library(RQuantLib)
R> setEvaluationDate(Sys.Date())
[1] TRUE
R>`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can (and maybe should) now "upvote" (click on upward triangle) the answer, and as the person asking it, can also "accept" it (click on tick-mark).  You too get points for accepting an answer.